# One to many relationship in REST design

Tags: rest

I have to tables users and teams. The application logic is such that every user should belong to atleast one team(No default here, user can initially belong to any team)

If I am using RESTful APIs to create users resource, should I send the info about user's team in this API itself.

```
POST /api/users
```

Or should I make 2 requests

```
POST /api/users
PUT /api/teams/{id}
```

If I use the second logic, there is an inconsistency in database if second API is never called.

What is the right thing to do in case of REST design?

Comment: what could cause that you don't send the second request?

Comment: Anything like network failure, client shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

What about `POST /api/teams/{id}/users`.
The URI is self explanatory, you are posting a user directly in a the appropriate team.